# Regular expression: How to match string without the last digits?

Tags: regex, preg-match

This is my string: `left_image_12`.

I would like to leave out `_12` and only display `left_image`. I am unable to figure this out.

Comment: What is the definition of what you are trying to parse?  Is it the first two words separated by `_`?  Is it everything but the final `_` and number?  Give more examples of input and output

Comment: `preg_match('#(.*?)_\d+$#i',$str,$match);echo $match[1];`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with a capture group:

```
^(.*?)_\d+$
```

$1 (or \1, depending on your language) will contain the name without the number at the end.

Comment: Great! Do I really need `?` in the above RE? I think it matches the text correctly without `?` as well.

Comment: The `?` is to prevent the expression from being greedy.  If you ever change your requirements you'll be glad the `?` is there. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
preg_match($string, "/^([A-Za-z_]+)_\d+$/", $match);
$output = $match[1];
```